# Confused Pip install with Virtual Environments

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

Probably a rookie question: I created a project folder, cd'ed to it, created a virtual environment via

```
python -m venv .venv
```

and it made the VE in the right place with what looks like the right stuff. But pip-installing modules *sometimes* (??) fails, with the module going into the global site-packages. This is a vanilla Python 3.9 install on Linux (Raspberry Pi) and being used within Visual Studio Code. To get it right I need to use the "Pip Manager" extension. Why?? To illustrate my confusion, I understand that Python (and Pip?) uses **sys.path** to resolve packages (see [XKCD 1897](https://xkcd.com/1987/)). So after activating the VE, I looked and got this? I expected to see the **.venv** site-packages in that path *first*, right? Well here is what I get:
[image: terminal snapshot]
Where am I misinformed or otherwise confused?

**Info added in response to questions below**

This system never had Python2 on it. Within the activated .venv there are links:

```
pi@rpi1:~/Documents/alpyca-device*.venv/bin $ ls -l pyt*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi 15 Dec 14 14:41 python -> /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi  6 Dec 14 14:41 python3 -> python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi  6 Dec 14 14:41 python3.9 -> python
```

and this is the usual way it is put into the Python3 virtuals by the venv module, which is recommended now over virtualenv and other schemes.

```
(.venv) pi@rpi1:~/Documents/alpyca $ which python
/home/pi/Documents/alpyca/.venv/bin/python
```

and other requests for info:

```
(.venv) pi@rpi1:~/Documents/alpyca $ grep VIRTUAL_ENV= .venv/bin/activate
VIRTUAL_ENV="/home/pi/Documents/alpyca/.venv"

(.venv) pi@rpi1:~/Documents/alpyca $ .venv/bin/python
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/usr/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.9', '/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/home/pi/Documents/alpyca/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
>>>
```

I don't know about Python 2, I have never used it.

Comment: try creating your EV without the dot, so: python - m venv venv. as well it is normal to have reference to your installed package. in your example installed libs would be in /home/pi/.local/lib/xxx, but not sure about the .local and on my ubuntu the path match my EV path...

Comment: Have you tried using the `python3` command from within your venv? It's possible that the `python` variable is not being bound by your venv, since this used to refer to python 2 installations.

Comment: Please show the output of `which python`

Comment: @wovano I apologize for not carefully reading your request. OK I moved all of my response info up into the question. Also I am somewhat new to Python 3, and for now I am OK with stuff being mixed up between the global site-packages and the .venv. I just want to understand why this isn't working so I can clean it all up later. It seems like the `activate` process is broken.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question and providing additional info. As you can see in the latest output, the .venv path is included in your `sys.path`. So this seems to work as intended. There might be something broken with your activate process, but apparently this is not reproducable. Is it possible that you once did `. .venv/bin/activate` instead of `.venv/bin/activate`. It's pretty easy to miss the additional `.` which makes a big difference in this case.

Comment: @wovano Thanks again. I suspect I have a fundamental misunderstanding or that the Visual Studio Code "interpreter" selector is not behaving. I can see that VSCode thinks is using the virtual environment (along the status line on the bottom).  I got myself into trouble trying to get Sphinx and Rinoh working, with pip informing me of version conflicts galore (package A requires package B version <M and <N but some other package installed the latest version M+1) and things fell apart quickly. I appreciate your showing me how to see where Python is looking and what it is seeing. Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to be of help. Note that activating a virtual environment is purely for convenience, it does nothing really important. Just executing the correct Python interpreter (i.e. the python executable in your virtual environment) is really all that's needed. Getting venvs to work smoothly in VS Code is a completely different story. There are many questions and answers about that on Stack Overflow. Make sure to include the [visual-studio-code] tag when you search further for solutions.

Comment: To me the venv is useful for maintaining a stable environment. I foolishly updated some packages in my global site packages,and the result was chaos as I described above.  once you get the "recipe" for  a particular task and you don't plan to develop in that environment, freeze it. Try to get Sphinx 6.0.0 installed with a few other things that use docutils and so forth. I could only get it all to work with Sphinx 4.5. Sigh. Well thanks again!!